# Not Regular This Time

Tags: magic-square

We can say that an $n$-by-$n$ square is regular provided that:

1. Each of the integers from $0$ to $n^2 − 1$ appears in exactly one cell, and each cell contains only one integer (so that the square is filled), and
2. If we express the entries in base-$n$ form, each base-$n$ digit occurs exactly once in the units’ position, and exactly once in the $n$’s position.

What is an example of a 4-by-4 filled, magic square which is not regular? The square should use the integers 0 to 15. Show the answer in both decimal and base-4 as well.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a irregular magic square? :P (I'm guessing its a stupid question, sorry :P )

Comment: @TheDragonista In my last question I defined what a regular square is.

Comment: My previous one was irregular, so shall i post that answer here and try finding a different solution for the other one?

Comment: I think Togashi already did

Comment: awesome....These magic squares have really been keeping me awake!! It's 2:30 am here! :P

Comment: Would it be possible for you to include in this question what you mean by a regular square? I'm pretty sure this isn't a term that most people know with regards to magic squares, and questions need to stand alone. Thank you!

Comment: @Emrakul I copied the definition from the OP's other question into this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally!! I've got it! :) :D

**Answer**

> [image]